# How to handle events from LWC datatable custom data types

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, datatable, refresh

I have created lightning data table **MyLightningDataTable** with a custom data type. This custom datatable is a child component of **MyDataGroup** component and **MyDataGroup** is a child of **MyData** component.

[image]

**MyData** component's *getData* method retrieves date from back-end. Then processes data and generates **processed_data** object as follows.

```js
    processed_data = [
        {group_id : 'group_name1',
         data     : [data1Obj1, data1Obj2, ...]},

        ...
    ];
```

Using these data it dynamically generated **MyGroupData** components(which has a **MyLightningDataTable** component). When Custom data type of this datatable fires an event I need to call the *getData* method of **MyData** component again. How can I achieve this?

Code segment relevant to this are indicated follow.

**MyData.js**

```js
    import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

    import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccounts'

    import FI_MID_ACCOUNT_FID_ANNUAL_REVENUE from '@salesforce/schema/Account.AnnualRevenue';
    import FI_MID_ACCOUNT_FID_DESCRIPTION from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Description';

    export default class MyData extends LightningElement {
        @track accounts;
        @track editableFields = [
            FI_MID_ACCOUNT_FID_ANNUAL_REVENUE,
            FI_MID_ACCOUNT_FID_DESCRIPTION
        ];

        @track columns = [
            {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'editableRecord', typeAttributes: { 
                    recordId:  {fieldName: 'Id'},                                                                                                
                    objApiName:'Account',                                                                                           
                    fieldList: this.editableFields,
                    updatedone: this.getData                                                                                                 
                },
            ...
        ];

        connectedCallback() {
            this.getData();
        }

        getData(){
            getAccounts()
            .then(result => {
                this.accounts = result;
                this.processAccounts(this.accounts);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.accounts = undefined;
            });
        }

        processAccounts() {
            //generates processed_data object.
        }
    }
```

**MyData.html**

```html
    <template>
        <template if:true={processed_data}>
            <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle}
                active-section-name={}>
                <template for:each={processed_data} for:item="account_group">
                    <lightning-accordion-section key={account_group.group_id} name={account_group.group_id} label={account_group.group_id}>
                        <c-my-data-group
                            group-id={audit_group.group_id}
                            data-list={audit_group.data}
                            columns={columns}>
                        </c-my-data-group>
                    </lightning-accordion-section>
                </template>
            </lightning-accordion>
        </template>
    </template>
```

**MyDataGroup.js**

```js
    export default class CurrentAuditsGroup extends LightningElement {
        @api groupId;
        @api dataList;
        @api columns;
    }
```

**MyDataGroup.html**

```html
    <templete>
        <c-current-audits-lightning-table key={groupId} data={dataList} key-field="Id" columns={columns}>
        </c-current-audits-lightning-table>
    </template>
```

**editableRecord.js**

```js
    import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
    import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

    export default class EditableRecord extends LightningElement {
        @api displayText;
        @api recordId;
        @api objApiName;
        @api fieldList;

        @track openViewRecord;

        expandRecord() {
            this.openViewRecord = true;
        }

        closeViewRecord() {
            this.openViewRecord = false;
        }

        onUpdateSuccess() {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Records updated',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            // This event should be caught at MyData
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('refresh'));

            this.closeViewRecord();
        }
    }
```

**editableRecord.html**

```html
    <template>
        <span class="slds-text-link_faux">
            <lightning-formatted-text onclick={expandRecord} value={displayText} linkify></lightning-formatted-text>
        </span>

        <template if:true={openViewRecord}>
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={closeViewRecord}>
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="medium">
                            </lightning-icon>
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <h2 id="confirmation-modal-heading-1" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">{displayText}</h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_large" id="confirmation-modal-content-id-1">
                            <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId}
                            object-api-name={objApiName} onsuccess={onUpdateSuccess}>
                                <lightning-messages>
                                </lightning-messages>
                                <template for:each={fieldList} for:item="field">
                                    <lightning-input-field key={field.fieldApiName} field-name={field.fieldApiName}>
                                    </lightning-input-field>
                                </template>
                                <lightning-button
                                    class="slds-m-top_small"
                                    variant="brand"
                                    type="submit"
                                    name="update"
                                    label="Update">
                                </lightning-button>
                            </lightning-record-edit-form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning-button label="Cancel" variant="neutral" onclick={closeViewRecord}></lightning-button>
                    </footer> -->
                </div>
            </section>
                <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </template>
    </template>
```

**MyLightningDataTable.js**

```js
    import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
    import editableRecordHtml from './editableRecordTemplate.html';
    export default class CurrentAuditsLightningTable extends LightningDatatable {

        static customTypes = {
            editableRecord: {
                template        : editableRecordHtml,
                typeAttributes  : ['displayText', 'recordId', 'objApiName', 'fieldList', 'updatedone' ]
            }
        };
    }
```

**MyLightningDataTable.html**

```html
    <template>
    </template>
```

**editableRecordTemplate.html**

```html
    <template>
        <c-editable-record
            display-text={value}
            record-id={typeAttributes.recordId}
            obj-api-name={typeAttributes.objApiName}
            field-list={typeAttributes.fieldList}
            onupdated={typeAttributes.updatedone}>
        </c-editable-record>
    </template>
```

---

### **UPDATE**

I was able to set an `getData()` function in typeAttributes and call it at `onupdated()` event. This function is working fine when it is called at `connectedCallback()`. But when it is calling with the event, javascript stops with an error saying `processAccount()` function is undefined.

I have updated the code accordingly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got through it. I had to dispatch event with `composed` and `bubbles` attributes as follows.

```
const event = CustomEvent('refresh', {
    composed: true,
    bubbles: true
});
this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Then I added event binding at `MyDataGroup.html`

```
<c-current-audits-lightning-table
    key={groupId}
    data={dataList}
    key-field="Id"
    columns={columns}
    onrefresh={refreshHandler}>
</c-current-audits-lightning-table>
```

After this setup when I clicked the button, `refreshHandler()` at `MyDataGroup.js` was called as expected.

### Even though this solved my problem, I still do not know why I needed to set `bubbles` and `composed` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

1. Create an event handler on the parents.
2. Add the on"mycustomevent" prop on your components
3. Dispatch event with payload from children

```html
<!-- eventSimple.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-card title="EventSimple" icon-name="custom:custom9">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <p class="slds-m-vertical_medium content">Page {page}</p>
            <c-paginator 
              onprevious={previousHandler} <!--these are the handlers on the parent-->
              onrefresh={refreshHandler}
            ></c-paginator>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Here is the parent JS:

```js
// eventSimple.js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class EventSimple extends LightningElement {
    @track page = 1;

    previousHandler() {
        if (this.page > 1) {
            this.page = this.page - 1;
        }
    }

    refreshHandler() {
        this.page = this.page + 1;
    }
}
```

Here is the Child JS:

```js
// paginator.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Paginator extends LightningElement {
    previousHandler() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('previous')); //this is the prop without 'on'
    }

    nextHandler() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('refresh')); //this is the prop without 'on'
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was able to handle events from child according to the way you've mentioned. But in my case event fires from actually from a data type. It seems that is pretty different. It was not working for me as usual.

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to dispatch data from an event? you can send the data in the detail object:

{detail: {
  Stuff
}}

Comment: Actually not. See my ```editableRecord.js``` It dispatch an event called refresh. i need to handle that event at ```MyData.js```

Comment: I think either you're not reading the response or I am not understanding your question: use an attribute called onrefresh to capture the event